# Extract data from website after USER interaction

Tags: html, iframe, web-applications, web, data-extraction

I am trying to create a web application in which the application extracts data from a 3rd party website after the user interacts with it.

For example: a user logs on to xyz.com and enters some values in the the form and clicks on the submit button and a new page appears, now my application will extract this data and store it in the db for future reference of the user.

I tried to do this with `<iframe>` but some websites seem to be blocking this request. I would love it if someone could help me solve this problem.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky situation because of the access limitations from some other sites (as pointed out by Eric).

The easy answer is to build a form with the same inputs as the site in question, and then have an ajax request post to the processor and then parse the results into the database.  the problem with this is that most sites don't allow cross-browser posting or scraping unless there is an API involved.

Most common for AJAX is:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://my.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Even doing a jquery ".contents()" yields:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://my.domain.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.test.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

so unless you have the other sites cooperation, you might be out of luck.

Comment: but even if this is possible the problem is that inputs vary from site to site!

Comment: This is definitely true - I don't think there is a blanket way to extract output from submission on other sites, because:
A) Inputs differ from place to place and
B) Output differs from place to place....

Best thing I can recommend is see if the sites offer some sort of API for data and use it that way :/

I have tried this before with little to no results without site cooperation, so I feel your pain.